# How do I center these two divs with the container being displayed inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble centering these two floated left divs into a container which has a height of auto and a display set to `inline-block`. I've given my container a max-width of 1600px and when the window is stretched wider than 1600px, the container stays pinned to the left. I tried text `align:center`, and `margin:0 auto`, on the container but I'm not getting the result I'm looking for.

Here is my code.

```css
.keyfacts {
 width: 94%;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 1600px;
 padding: 60px 3% 60px 3%;
 background-color: #634A4B;
 display: inline-block;
}

.keyfactsleft {
 float: left;
 width: 47%;
 height: auto;
 padding-right: 3%;
}

.keyfactsleft p {
 font-family: 'Raleway', san-serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 32px;
 font-weight: 100;
    color: #58595b;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.keyfactsright {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 465px;
    background-image: url(_images/meredith-manor-aerial.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: #A05B5C;
}
```

```html
<section class="keyfacts">
 <div class="keyfactsleft">
     <h3 class="red">When</h3>
        <p>Saturday, October 14, 2017 at Five in the Evening</p>
        <h3 class="red">Where</h3>
        <p>Meredith Manor<br>2270 Pottstown Pike, Pottstown, PA 19465</p>
        <p>Our convenient venue will host both our ceremony and our reception. Its location is only a few miles down the road from the Hilton Garden Inn, where you’ll be sleeping if you plan on getting wild and staying over.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="keyfactsright"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see this working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/s8rL8e8v/
if your content has a height, you dont need to put height on your container div. just put `overflow:hidden` and it will cope all the content inside it and put some `padding`.

```
.keyfacts {
        width: 94%;
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 60px 3% 60px 3%;
    background: #634A4B
}

.keyfactsleft {
    float: left;
    width: 47%;
    height: auto;
    padding-right: 3%;
}

.keyfactsleft p {
    font-family: 'Raleway', san-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #58595b;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.keyfactsright {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 465px;
    background-image: url(_images/meredith-manor-aerial.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: #A05B5C;
}
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Im glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the parent container to be centered, then `div.keyfacts` must be a block level element, for example, `display: block` or `display: table`.

In both cases, `margin: 0 auto` will center the container.

Since you are specifying the width for `div.keyfacts`, then either choice will work.

(I adjusted the `width` and `max-width` values for demonstration only.)

```css
.keyfacts {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 450px;
  padding: 60px 3% 60px 3%;
  background-color: #634A4B;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.keyfactsleft {
  float: left;
  width: 47%;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 3%;
}
.keyfactsleft p {
  font-family: 'Raleway', san-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #58595b;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.keyfactsright {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 465px;
  background-image: url(_images/meredith-manor-aerial.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: #A05B5C;
}
```

```html
<section class="keyfacts">

  <div class="keyfactsleft">

    <h3 class="red">When</h3>

    <p>Saturday, October 14, 2017 at Five in the Evening</p>

    <h3 class="red">Where</h3>

    <p>Meredith Manor
      <br>2270 Pottstown Pike, Pottstown, PA 19465</p>

    <p>Our convenient venue will host both our ceremony and our reception. Its location is only a few miles down the road from the Hilton Garden Inn, where you’ll be sleeping if you plan on getting wild and staying over.</p>

  </div>

  <div class="keyfactsright"></div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do:

`body { text-align: center }` to center the `.keyfacts`, but this will require you to do `.keyfacts { text-align: left }`

I would go with `.keyfacts { display: block, margin: 0 auto }` instead.

If an element is `display: inline-block`, then the parent will need a `text-align: center` to center the element, but this affects all children elements within the container.

If an element is `display: block`, then applying `margin: 0 auto` on the element itself (NOT THE PARENT) will center the element.